# Передача о обработка строк сервером от трех клиентов

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокеты

> Несколько клиентов шлют на сервер строки. Сервер сравнивает их и
>   пересылает информацию клиентам. Протокол взаимодействия TCP

Собственно сейчас клиент шлет строку, сервер получает ее и шлет обратно. А нужно сделать так, чтобы 1 клиент послал строку - в ответ ничего, 2 клиент присылает - в ответ обоим результат вычислений, затем 3 присылает - в ответ другой результат всем 3 клиентам. 
Язык C/C++

Сервер

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
   int sock, listener;
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   char buf[1024];
   int bytes_read;

   listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if(listener < 0){
      perror("socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){
      perror("bind");
      exit(2);
   } 

   listen(listener, 1);
   while(1){
      sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
      if(sock < 0){
         perror("accept");
         exit(3);
      }

      while(1){
         bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);

         if(bytes_read <= 0) break;
         send(sock, buf, bytes_read, 0);
      }
      close(sock);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Клиент

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

char message[] = "Hello there!\n"; char buf[sizeof(message)]; 

int main() {
   int sock;
   struct sockaddr_in addr;

   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if(sock < 0){
      perror("socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port = htons(3425); // или любой другой порт...
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
   if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){
      perror("connect");
      exit(2);
   }

   send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);
   recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);
   printf(buf);
   printf("sock = %d", sock);
   close(sock); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если клиентов ожидается не много, посмотрите функцию `select()` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html. Если много - смотрите в сторону `epoll()`. Это что бы ожидание данных от одного клиента не останавливало сервер и можно было независимо ожидать данных от нескольких клиентов. А отсылать не сложно, у вас наверняка будет какой нибудь массив соединений с клиентами, обходите его и делаете для каждого send

Comment: Поясните проблему точнее.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего будет воспользоваться библиотекой [libevent](http://libevent.org/), вот пример реализации сервера при помощи данной библиотеки. [Библиотека libevent для асинхронного неблокирующего ввода/вывода: Часть 4. Сетевые приложения](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-Libevent4/)

Также могу порекомендовать классическое решение посредством функции [fork](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm)